# Keras model.predict() giving only one prediction

Tags: python, keras, data-science, prediction

I trained a model, it shows all 4 predictions and saved it in json format. When I try to load it and do the prediction, it shows only one prediction. What could be going on?

My code:

```
test = pd.read_csv('./Data/test.tsv', sep="\t")
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer,WordNetLemmatizer
stemmer=SnowballStemmer('english')
lemma=WordNetLemmatizer()
from string import punctuation
import re
testing = test.Phrase.apply(lambda x: x.lower())
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words= 10000)
X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(testing.values)

X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=48)
json_file = open('model1.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()    
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

# Load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights('model1.h5') 
loaded_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                     optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
                     metrics=['accuracy'])

prediction = model.predict_classes(X_test,verbose=1)
model.summary()#while training
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, None, 100)         1373200   
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, None, 64)          42240     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                12416     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 165       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,428,021
Trainable params: 1,428,021
Non-trainable params: 0
print(X_test.shape)
(66292, 48)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What do you mean with it shows only one prediction? Do you mean that it makes a prediction for only one class or do you mean that it makes a prediction only for one rows (out of four) in X_test? Printing loaded_model. summary() and pasting it here would help too. Can you also add the shape of `X_test`?

Comment: If you are trying to say that it is only returning one "class", while your training set was four classes? It sounds like you may looking for a return of values that suggest "fitness" for each class?

Comment: actually i had trained the model for sentiment analytics .it has four classes 0,1,2,3,4.When i trained my  model and do the prediction it works fine with output(0,1,2,3,4) .When i load the model from json and do the prediction in the data set it shows only one result that is 2.It should show all 4 classes prediction .

Comment: I posted the answer below. Hope I understand your issue correctly. If not, please add expected output and the real output and add the model summary (l`oaded_model. summary() `).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly the problem is here:
`predict_classes` will return you the final predicted label, not probabilities. It will return one of four labels which has the highest probability. If you want the probabilities for each class, you should probably use `predict_proba` or `predict` which are same, e.g.:

```
prediction = model.predict(X_test,verbose=1)
```

Comment: done the  same when i try to save Prediction its throw me error that data must be 1D Below is the code which i use to save the prediction:prediction = pd.DataFrame({
        "phrase": test["Phrase"],
        "Sentiments":prediction
    })

Comment: I had updated code .This model summary i got when i trained the model and saved it.

Comment: i tried predict_proba  also it gives me only one prediction 0.110344835 for all inputs

Answer (score 0):

Error has been resolved it didn't tokanize test values properly.Below command remove the error

```
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(testing.values)
```